# Parse dynamic string in java

Tags: java, substring

I want to parse string like this:

`String str = 6,image micky.jpeg:7,image 02.jpeg:8,img3;`

in java. In this `6`,`7`,`8` are ids and there can be any number of ids in a dynamic string.

I want to find the array of ids from this string how to do that.

Comment: split by `:`, then split by `,`

Comment: @AnkitHTech my solution returns the array you desire. accept it please.

Comment: @AnkitHTech I believe you want to develop yourself, so I will leave declaring the array of ids and adding ids to the array for you. I hope that my mini-guide to split method will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or [split(...) method of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) class.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of split method with ":" parameter. The [split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method(used on a String *object*) returns an array of Strings, that were separated in the *object* by a *regex*. In this case it will return an array like:

> {"6,image micky,jpeg","7,image 02.jpeg","8,img3"}

Then you can iterate through this array and use split again. This time with "," as a parameter. Then you need to take 1st value from the result array.

```
String[] array = str.split(":");
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  String[] innerData = array[i].split(",");
  String id = innerData[0];
  System.out.println(id);
}
```

or

```
String[] array = str.split(":");
for(String s : array){
  String[] innerData = s.split(",");
  String id = innerData[0];
  System.out.println(id);
}
```

In both cases String id is what you are looking for.

If you would try

```
String[] array = str.split(",");
```

In the first place, the resulting array would look like:

> {"6","image micky.jpeg:7","image 02.jpeg:8","img3"}

Answer (score 2):

```
    String str = "6,image micky.jpeg:7,image 02.jpeg:8,img3";
    String[] array = str.split(":");

    int[] ids = new int[array.length]; // Array of ids.
    int index = 0;

    for (String s : array) 
    {
        String[] subArray = s.split(",");

        try
        {
            ids[index++] = Integer.valueOf(subArray[0]);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using StringTokenizer

```
     String str = "6,image micky.jpeg:7,image 02.jpeg:8,img3";

     StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(str, ":");
     while (tk.hasMoreElements()) {
        String elem = (String) tk.nextElement();

        StringTokenizer tk1 = new StringTokenizer(elem, ",");

         if (tk1.hasMoreElements()) {
                String elem1 = (String) tk1.nextElement();
                System.out.println(elem1.charAt(0));
         }      

     }
```